# Django forms not working on DigitalOcean Server

Tags: python, django, forms, deployment, digital-ocean

Hi I've recently been trying to deploy a Django web app on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 16.4 server, and was finally able to have the views load with uWSGI, nginx, and lets encrypt for a secure connection. My only issue is: there are a few views which rely on submitting a django form to retrieve objects based on distance from the user (GeoDjango query in the view). The form in question looks like this:

```
<form method= 'get' action="/foo/">{% csrf_token %}
        <input  id='latload'  type= 'number' step='any' value='0' name='latitude' style="display:none">
        <input  id='lonload'  type= 'number' step='any' value='0' name='longitude' style="display:none">




    <p id= 'walltext' >Here you can listen to the sounds in your area. To use your current location, click 
    </p>


    <input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' id='submit' value='here' style="color:#1d3b77; font-size: 25px; width: 100%;" disabled />
</form>
```

It takes the lat and long retrieved from a previous Javascript getLocation() function, then is passed to the /foo/ view through the form, which queries objects by distance (GeoDjango) and looks like this:

```
def fetch_places_loc(request):
    lat= request.GET['latitude']
    lon= request.GET['longitude']
    finder_location = Point(float(lon),float(lat))

    nearby= Places.objects.filter(
        location__distance_lte=(
            finder_location,
            D(km=40))).distance(finder_location).order_by('distance').order_by('-rating__average')[:10]
    context= {
        'object_listboy': nearby,
        'title': 'wall',

    }
    return render(request, 'location/wall.html', context)
```

Now, on the development server, it all works together and returns the nearest 10 objects. After Git cloning the project to the DigitalOcean server and configuring the uWSGI, NGINX, and securing the connection with let's encrypt, The view doesn't return any results. It redirects to the "wall" page, with no objects in the list. I'm not getting any sort of errors in the browser console, and all the javascript is working as it should (returns lat and long with console.log(), and puts it into the Django form). Anyone with any insight into what's up? I've been working on the website for a while now and having trouble so close to being finished. My instincts point to maybe an incorrect nginx server config or something. Let me know if you'd like to see any configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you werent getting `latitude` and `longitude` in the request, then the code would have thrown error as you have written - `request.GET['latitude']`

So, I guess the query is returning no results. You can debug this by using the django shell on the server and then running the database query with some values there.

Answer (score 0):

un display:none and check if there is some data in the form filled with javascript, I'm pretty sure you have to allow site to geolocate you